# iOS background image on top of collection view

Tags: ios, background-image, uicollectionview

I have an image which I want to use as a background of `ViewController` with a `CollectionView` but it is blocking out the `UICollection` Items. It is smaller than the `background` `width` or `height` so `self.view.backgroundColor` is not going to work for me.

My background looks like this:

```
 logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];

logo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.collectionView addSubview:logo];
[self.collectionView sendSubviewToBack:logo];

[logo sendSubviewToBack:logo];
```

There are some `NSLayout` constraints defining how the image will float. Everything is fine with this except that the image blocks out the `UICollection` items.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try setting the `backgroundView` property of the collection view to the desired view (`logo`). I'm guessing the problem is that if you're using the UICollectionViewController class, then the collection view itself is the parent view. And you can't send a subview behind the parent view.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It has helped, but a problem remains: The image is not the same size and scale as the view, so backgroundView works correctly, however, the image is stretched vertically, thus being unusable.

Comment: architect pianist... is that some kind of Weeds reference?

Answer (score 1):

Do your complete class inherite `UICollectionViewController` or is it a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` inside?

if your class is of `UICollectionViewController`, than you cant send the logo to back, because it always have to be infront of the `rootview`, so the `UICollectionView`.

Otherways try `[self sendSubviewToBack:logo];` instead of `[logo sendSubviewToBack:logo];`.

and is the

```
logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];

logo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

part to make the logo fullsize or what is the expected behaviour? i think there is a better way so you even don't need to use a separate logo but the normal `backgound`.

but can tell you later, have my code and IDE not here ^^

---

to change your `UICollectionViewController` to a `UIViewController`, you can use this code

// myClass.h

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
{
    // ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UICollectionView *collectionView;
    //...

@end
```

// myClass.m

```
// do imports

@implementation myClass

@synthesize collectionView;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:anyLayout];

    UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];
    logo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.view addSubview:logo];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:logo];
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure how to tell if it inherits UICollectionViewController or UINavigationController. This is my interface in the header: 

@interface WUUViewController : UICollectionViewController

There is a navigationBar in my viewController.

Comment: the "... : UICollectionViewController" tells, that the parent class is a UICollectionViewController, so it is also the base you are working with. I would recommend to set set "@interface @interface WUUViewController : UINavigationController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>". I'll update my answer to fit your requirentments

Comment: Hmmm... I think this is works, but... my collection view items are not visible now, so I can't really tell. I assume they need their own view now?

Comment: think you have to add self.collectionView.delegate = self; ^^ tried this already? and same with datasource :P

Comment: I have done everything you recommended including changing the class to  UIViewController. Now everything shows up but I've got the same problem.

Comment: same problem means blocking the UICollection items? :/

Comment: yeah : ( Tried a few other things such as [self.view insertSubLayer atIndex:0];, or self.collectionView... I know there's a solution but just haven't gotten to it yet.

Comment: too bad, can test it monday first, have no IDE here at home for it. but can you possibly make a screenshot of it? maybe I will see more :/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the controller type you have, you can use this code:

If your controller is a `UIViewController`:

```
 self.view.backgroundColor= 
       [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

If your controller is a `UICollectionViewController`:

```
 self.collectionView.backgroundView= 
       [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```